# Create new item in Firebase using form

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a web app for a party planning iOS app and I want to have a form where users can create new events through a web form that is submitted using that data.(Sounds better in my head :/ )
In our database there is a tree called "events" where all the events and their details are stored. As an example let's say that I want a form to post the name of the event and the date of the event then have it be stored under the event tree.

After looking at the firebase documentation for a while it seemed like using the update/add user snippet could be the framework for this project.

```
user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

But instead of using "Jane Q. User" I would want to call a form field and its data. Am I going about this the right direction or am I up the wrong tree?